# How to memoize a part of a component list in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, render, react-usememo

Looking for some React rendering/useMemo guidance.

I have a list of 2,000+ items, each of which is a React component. There is a highlight of a "currently selected" item that renders independently of the list. That allows me to render the list only once.

```js
useMemo(_ => {
  <Item .../>
  <Item .../>
  ...
  <Item .../>
}, [contents])
```

Now I'm adding the ability to "expand" a list item in it, which only adds new DOM elements without modifying the list item in its non-expanded state.

You can imagine each `Item` being two parts:

```js
function Item(props) {
  return
    <div>
      <SubItem />
      {
        if (props.open) {
          <OtherItem />
        } else {
          null
        }
      }
    </div>
}
```

```js
useMemo(_ => {
  <Item open={1 == current} .../>
  <Item open={2 == current} .../>
  ...
  <Item open={n == current} .../>
}, [contents, current])
```

**Question: Is there a way to support this without having to re-render the whole list every time I expand/collapse a new item?**

Unfortunately the expanded DOM elements are "in flow", so the expansion pushes list items after it (not just a hover/overlay thing).

Comment: i think you will have to memo the `ITEM` function component

Comment: @kunalpanchal interesting, small clarification on the Items, the 2000 items are not explicitly listed out but I'm creating them using a map function. How would I memo individual Items in that context?

Answer (score 5):

I think you can do it this way:

```
const Item = useMemo( props => {
    return (
        //...your JSX code here.
    )
}, []);

[...2000].map(props => <Item {...props}>);
```

Comment: I think that should be `const Item = React.memo((props) => {...})`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct, the component still re-renders e.g., 2k times.

Answer (score 0):

Memoizing the list item alone would not work because the `open` or `openIndex` state is in the parent `List`, not the `Item` itself.

The only workaround I see is to split the list into chunks of let's say 10 items, and memoize those chunks instead.

You would then use `React.memo` second parameter `arePropsEqual` to determine whether the list chunk should re-render, i.e. whether it includes the `prevProps.openIndex` or `nextProps.openIndex`.

For a large list like yours, this is well worth the effort.

Check out a demo here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/memoizedlistchunks